# bmuschko - gradle tomcat plugin - can I pass tomcat server.xml?

Tags: tomcat, plugins, gradle

I started using bmuschko gradle-tomcat-plugin, but I wondered if there is a way to pass tomcat server.xml?  I need to pass SSL Connector config info, but the system I'm working on uses APR so that I need to pass SSLCertificateFile, SSLCertificateKeyFile, and etc (instead of keystorefile, and etc), but it looks like there is no way to set them.  so I'm thinking if there is a way to pass server.xml??

Any help would be very appreciated!!

slee

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problm myself. As of now, there seems to be no solution to this.
As [this blog post](https://kishanthan.wordpress.com/2013/05/12/embedded-tomcat-tips-tricks-and-hacks/) states, tomcat embedded doesn't support passing a server.xml. There's a workaround if you're creating an embedded instance yourself, but because the gradle-tomcat-plugin does that for you, you could only fix this by changing the plugin code.

Hope that helps and that this gets "fixed" soon.